# Calling a Capistrano task with argument from other task

Tags: capistrano

I have a Capistrano 2 task that updates a file

```
task :update_file, roles: :app do
 ...
end
```

Now I need to write a task that performs the some operation on all the files within a folder so  from within `update_folder` I'd like to call `update_file` passing to it the name of the file to update but I have an hard time doing so.

How can I set a Capistrano task to accept an argument and call it from inside an other task?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
$gkey=""
$gvalue=""

desc "generate config files"
task :gen_conf_files do
    $servers.each do |key,value|
      $MYSQL["mysql"]["passwd"]="#{key.to_s}++"
      $gkey=key.to_s
      $gvalue=value.to_s
      $NODE_NAME="#{key.to_s}"
      $NODE_NUM=key.to_s[9,10]

      gen_mfs_conf
      gen_cfs_conf
      gen_client_conf
      gen_config_shell
      gen_cdn_reacheyes_net
      gen_click_reacheyes_net
      gen_log_reacheyes_net
      gen_fluent_conf
      gen_nagios_conf

  end
end

desc "genrate fluent config file"
task :gen_fluent_conf do
    file = "#{generate_conf_dir}/#{$gvalue}/fluent.conf"
    filename ="#{config_file_path}/fluent.conf.sample"
    erb = ERB.new(File.read(filename))
    erb.filename = filename
    File = File.new("#{file}", "w")
    File.puts erb.result
end
```

First define a global variable `$gvalue=""` then you can use this variable between different tasks.